# Add additional property in Linq to sql class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I added addition `PropIndustryNM` property to Linq-to-SQL table for data retrieving purpose. It's working fine.

But when I try to insert data into table, an error happens:

> *invalid column name 'PropIndustryNM'*

Now please give solution what can I do? I need both.

And I'm beginner ât Linq. So please suggest answer easy way which I can understand.

Add property in dbml file

this is a code in which i set value in this property.

```
    List<BIODATA_MA> list = new List<BIODATA_MA>();

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
    {
        BIODATA_MA c = new BIODATA_MA();
        INDUSTRY_MA im = new INDUSTRY_MA();

        c.ACCOUNT_ID = result.ElementAt(i).ACCOUNT_ID;
        c.FULL_NAME = result.ElementAt(i).FULL_NAME;
        c.RESUME_HEADELINE = result.ElementAt(i).RESUME_HEADELINE;
        c.KEY_SKILL = result.ElementAt(i).KEY_SKILL;
        c.TOTAL_EXPERIENCE = result.ElementAt(i).TOTAL_EXPERIENCE;
        c.PropIndustryNm = result.ElementAt(i).INDUSTRY;
        c.PropFunctionalNm = result.ElementAt(i).FUNCTIONAL_AREA;
        c.PropGraduNm = result.ElementAt(i).GRADU;
        c.PropPostGraduNm = result.ElementAt(i).POST_GRADU;
        //  c.TRANS_DATE = result.ElementAt(i).TRANS_DATE;
        list.Add(c);
    }
```

Its work fine.
But When insert time

```
        BIODATA_MA objBio = new BIODATA_MA();


        objBio.INDUSTRY_ID = int.Parse(ddlIndustry.SelectedItem.Value);
        objBio.FUNCTIONAL_AREA_ID = int.Parse(ddlFunctionalArea.SelectedItem.Value);

        if (ddlGradu.SelectedIndex > 0) objBio.GRADU_ID = int.Parse(ddlGradu.SelectedItem.Value); else objBio.GRADU_ID = 0;

        if (ddlPostGradu.SelectedIndex > 0) objBio.POST_GRADU_ID = int.Parse(ddlPostGradu.SelectedItem.Value); else objBio.POST_GRADU_ID = 0;

        if (ddlPhd.SelectedIndex > 0) objBio.PHD = ddlPhd.SelectedItem.Value;

        objBio.COURSE = txtCourse.Text;



        DCBiodataMasDataContext db = new DCBiodataMasDataContext();
        db.BIODATA_MAs.InsertOnSubmit(objBio);

        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
            lbMsg.Text = "added Successfully";
            clearAll();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lbMsg.Text = "not added.";
            throw;
        }
```

When insert data in to table with InsertOnSubmit()
It throw error like Invalid column Name 'PropIndustryNm'

I don't know what is my mistake.

Comment: Did you update the DBML after inserting new field in the table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1.** Try to remove all the table from your `model(dbml)` and drag-drop again from Server Explorer to your model and rebuild it again.

**Solution 2.** You had created properties(PropIndustryNM) from your table in the `model(dbml)` but not actually exist in the actual table from your database.

Just remove that `PropIndustryNM`, if you want to use the `table(BIODATA_MA)` in `dbml`, you could inherit that `table` from the model. Try to create a class.

```
public class BIODATA_MA_Entity : BIODATA_MA
{
   public string PropIndustryNM {get; set;}
}
```

Now, you can use like

```
List<BIODATA_MA_Entity> list = new List<BIODATA_MA_Entity>();

for (int i = 0; i < result.Count(); i++)
{
    BIODATA_MA c = new BIODATA_MA();
    INDUSTRY_MA im = new INDUSTRY_MA();

    c.ACCOUNT_ID = result.ElementAt(i).ACCOUNT_ID;
    c.FULL_NAME = result.ElementAt(i).FULL_NAME;
    c.RESUME_HEADELINE = result.ElementAt(i).RESUME_HEADELINE;
    c.KEY_SKILL = result.ElementAt(i).KEY_SKILL;
    c.TOTAL_EXPERIENCE = result.ElementAt(i).TOTAL_EXPERIENCE;
    c.PropIndustryNm = result.ElementAt(i).INDUSTRY;
    c.PropFunctionalNm = result.ElementAt(i).FUNCTIONAL_AREA;
    c.PropGraduNm = result.ElementAt(i).GRADU;
    c.PropPostGraduNm = result.ElementAt(i).POST_GRADU;
    //  c.TRANS_DATE = result.ElementAt(i).TRANS_DATE;
    list.Add(c);
}
```

> This ***update*** is not the answer but is a suggestion about the good
>   way to for coding with `class`. try to code like this
>
> ```
> BIODATA_MA objBio = new BIODATA_MA()
>  {
>      INDUSTRY_ID = int.Parse(ddlIndustry.SelectedItem.Value);
>      FUNCTIONAL_AREA_ID = int.Parse(ddlFunctionalArea.SelectedItem.Value);
>      //others  stuff
>  };
>
>  using (var db = new  DCBiodataMasDataContext())
>  {
>     db.BIODATA_MAs.InsertOnSubmit(objBio);
>  };
> ```

Comment: I add property and don't want to add this into table

Comment: But Now i m in trouble.what to do ??

Answer (score 0):

am not sure where those error has occurred.
 can it possible to see your piece of code, where you have declare this 'PropIndustryNM' Property?
In DB is there a column of such is Really available?

For your reference you can also check this link and try writing yours,

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/215712/LINQ-to-SQL-Basic-Concepts-and-Features

Possible share the Code, we try and Fix it.!

Answer (score 0):

It should be fixed with updating the table from your model.